# Failed to start Tomcat8 server on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, tomcat8, catalina

Trying to install Tomcat 8 on ubuntu 12.04 but I have this following problem with Catalina component  ,I think it's related to log files.

this is the command result:

```
~# $CATALINA_HOME/bin/startup.sh
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.15-src
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.15-src
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.15-src/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr/lib/jvm/default-java
Using CLASSPATH:       /opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.15-src/bin/bootstrap.jar:/opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.15-src/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
touch: cannot touch `/opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.15-src/logs/catalina.out': No such file or directory
/opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.15-src/bin/catalina.sh: 399: /opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.15-src/bin/catalina.sh: cannot create /opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.15-src/logs/catalina.out: Directory nonexistent
```

Update:
I tried to execute the last command as sudo . This is the output:

```
~# sudo $CATALINA_HOME/bin/startup.sh
sudo: /etc/sudoers.d/README is mode 0777, should be 0440
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.15-src
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.15-src
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.15-src/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr
Using CLASSPATH:       /opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.15-src/bin/bootstrap.jar:/opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.15-src/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
/opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.15-src/bin/catalina.sh: 399: /opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.15-src/bin/catalina.sh: cannot create /opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.15-src/logs/catalina.out: Directory nonexistent
```

Answer (score 1):

try to run it as sudo

```
sudo sh $CATALINA_HOME/bin/startup.sh
```

**Update:**

if you have installed tomcat by apt-get then you have to start it by service, try this-

```
sudo service tomcat start
sudo service tomcat stop
```